# Table sorter {page} and {size} returns empty instead of proper values

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am working tablesorter with pager plugin . I have managed to integrate this successfully . I am trying to implement AJAX pagination for this. So basically content will be loaded from Server side each time when user clicks on next/pre button . I am facing problem with {page} and {size} in tablesorter . These 2 variables inside table sorter is replaced with empty value instead of proper page and size value . Can any one help me with this ?

```
var ajax = "{f:uri.action(action: 'getAllFiles',noCacheHash: 1  )}";
$(function() {
    $("table")
        .tablesorter({  theme: 'blue', widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'pager'],})
        // ****************************
        // initialize the pager plugin
// ****************************
        .tablesorterPager({
          container: $(".pager"),
                  ajaxUrl : ajax+'&page={page}&size={size}&               {sortList:col}&{filterList:fcol}',
               customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) {
                // manipulate the url string as you desire
                //url += '&currPage=' +$('.curentpage').text();
            //console.log(table);
          // trigger a custom event; if you want
           $(table).trigger('changingUrl', url);
      // send the server the current page
      return url;
  },
  ajaxError: null,
   // add more ajax settings here
  // see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings
  ajaxObject: {
    dataType: 'json'
  },

  ajaxProcessing: function(data){
  console.log(data)
    if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('rows')) {
      var indx, r, row, c, d = data.rows,
      // total number of rows (required)
      total = data.total_rows,
      // array of header names (optional)
      headers = data.headers,
      // cross-reference to match JSON key within data (no spaces)
      headerXref = headers.join(',').replace(/\s+/g,'').split(','),
      // all rows: array of arrays; each internal array has the table cell data for that row
      rows = [],
      // len should match pager set size (c.size)
      len = d.length;
      // this will depend on how the json is set up - see City0.json
      // rows
      for ( r=0; r < len; r++ ) {
        row = []; // new row array
        // cells
        for ( c in d[r] ) {
          if (typeof(c) === "string") {
            // match the key with the header to get the proper column index
            indx = $.inArray( c, headerXref );
            // add each table cell data to row array
            if (indx >= 0) {
              row[indx] = d[r][c];
            }
          }
        }
        rows.push(row); // add new row array to rows array
      }
     // in version 2.10, you can optionally return $(rows) a set of table rows within a jQuery object
     return [total, rows, headers];
    }
  },
  // Set this option to false if your table data is preloaded into the table, but you are still using ajax
  processAjaxOnInit: true,

  // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}';
  // possible variables: {size}, {page}, {totalPages}, {filteredPages}, {startRow}, {endRow}, {filteredRows} and {totalRows}
  // also {page:input} & {startRow:input} will add a modifiable input in place of the value
  output: '<div class="curentpage">{page}</div> {startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})',

  // apply disabled classname (cssDisabled option) to the pager arrows when the rows
  // are at either extreme is visible; default is true
  updateArrows: true,

  // starting page of the pager (zero based index)
  page: 0,

  // Number of visible rows - default is 10
  size: 3,

  // Saves the current pager page size and number (requires storage widget)
  savePages: true,
  // Saves tablesorter paging to custom key if defined.
  // Key parameter name used by the $.tablesorter.storage function.
  // Useful if you have multiple tables defined
  storageKey: 'tablesorter-pager',

  // Reset pager to this page after filtering; set to desired page number (zero-based index),
  // or false to not change page at filter start
  pageReset: 0,

  // if true, the table will remain the same height no matter how many records are displayed.
  // The space is made up by an empty table row set to a height to compensate; default is false
  fixedHeight: false,

  // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables.
  // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed if you plan to
  // add/remove rows with the pager enabled.
  removeRows: false,

  // If true, child rows will be counted towards the pager set size
  countChildRows: false,

  // css class names of pager arrows
  cssNext        : '.next',  // next page arrow
  cssPrev        : '.prev',  // previous page arrow
  cssFirst       : '.first', // go to first page arrow
  cssLast        : '.last',  // go to last page arrow
  cssGoto        : '.gotoPage', // page select dropdown - select dropdown that set the "page" option

  cssPageDisplay : '.pagedisplay', // location of where the "output" is displayed
  cssPageSize    : '.pagesize', // page size selector - select dropdown that sets the "size" option

  // class added to arrows when at the extremes; see the "updateArrows" option
  // (i.e. prev/first arrows are "disabled" when on the first page)
  cssDisabled    : 'disabled', // Note there is no period "." in front of this class name
  cssErrorRow    : 'tablesorter-errorRow' // error information row
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using the provided `ajaxProcessing` function. If it doesn't match your JSON data, nothing will be returned. Are you seeing any rows in the table? Please see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/uwZc2/) for reference. It processes data from filltext.com for display (so sorting & filtering don't work in that demo).

Comment: Yes I can see result for this configuration . Thanks for the demo , now In my local environment  I am getting proper result ie {page} and {size} is replaced correctly . But I tested the script in in product environment there again {page} and {size} is replaced with empty values

Comment: Local url [link]http://localhost/fileupload/index.php?id=1&id=1&no_cache=1&tx_kwomedia_kwomedia[action]=getAllFiles&tx_kwomedia_kwomedia[controller]=Kwomedia&page=0&size=10&col&fcol[link]
PRD URL 
[link]http://xxxxxxxxxxxo/index.php?id=319&id=319&tx_kwomedia_kwomedia%5Baction%5D=getAllFiles&tx_kwomedia_kwomedia%5Bcontroller%5D=Kwomedia&page=&size=&col&fcol[link] @Mottie

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you... did you figure out the problem? Try adding a `console.log(url)` inside of the `customAjaxUrl` callback and see if the url is being processed correctly. If you need to chat, please use [IRC or gitter to contact me](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter#questions).